# how to Limit Login to User with verified e-mail address

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm in small project login form and i used Parse.com to save my users.

So , i have a problem in over there. i don't know how to check veritifed e-maill of user. i turned on "veritifed e-maill" ,when user sign up new user an email will send to user's email.
But when user login the app isn't check veritifed e-mail..

This is my login code :

```
private void logingin(EditText user,EditText pass) {
    final ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    dlg.setTitle(getString(R.string.log_in));
    dlg.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait));
            dlg.show();
    // Call the Parse login method
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(user.getText().toString(), pass.getText()
            .toString(), new LogInCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            dlg.dismiss();
            if (e != null) {
                // Show the error message
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // Start an intent for the dispatch activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FindActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described [in the User section of the guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#users).

> Verifying Emails
>
> Enabling email verification in an application's settings allows the
>   application to reserve part of its experience for users with confirmed
>   email addresses. Email verification adds the emailVerified key to the
>   ParseUser object. When a ParseUser's email is set or modified,
>   emailVerified is set to false. Parse then emails the user a link which
>   will set emailVerified to true.
>
> There are three emailVerified states to consider:
>
> true - the user confirmed his or her email address by clicking on the
>   link Parse emailed them. ParseUsers can never have a true value when
>   the user account is first created. false - at the time the ParseUser
>   object was last fetched, the user had not confirmed his or her email
>   address. If emailVerified is
>
> false, consider calling fetch() on the
>   ParseUser.
>
> missing - the ParseUser was created when email verification
>   was off or the ParseUser does not have an email.

So, once you have a ParseUser object, just get the verified state of that user:

```
private void logingin(EditText user,EditText pass) {
    final ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    dlg.setTitle(getString(R.string.log_in));
    dlg.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait));
            dlg.show();
    // Call the Parse login method
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(user.getText().toString(), pass.getText()
            .toString(), new LogInCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            dlg.dismiss();
            if (e != null) {
                // Show the error message
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                boolean emailVerified = user.getBoolean("emailVerified"); //added
                if (emailVerified) {
                  // Email for this user verified, Start an intent for the dispatch activity
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FindActivity.class);
                  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                  //TODO: handle non-verified state
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```